# Access value depending on its location in array jstl forEach

Tags: java, arrays, jstl

I am attepting to do this for the first time. I have an ArrayList Method which I need to access each value separately in foreach loop: This is what I have tried to access the first element and the second in the ArrayList:

```
<forEach var = "item" items = "${obj.allusers}">
<tr style = "height:30px;padding:4px">
<td><div align = "center">${item}[0]</div><td>
<td><div align = "center">${item}[1]</div><td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

this is giving me errro`Property '1' not found for type java.lang.String`
how Can I access each element independently in the loop?

Comment: Do you want to print the '0'th and '1'st character of the user?

Comment: I thought arrays Start from 0 so I want the first and the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `varStatus` attribute in the `forEach` tag that you can use for this purpose. 
e.g.,

```
<tr style = "height:30px;padding:4px">
 <c:forEach var = "item" items = "${obj.allusers}" varStatus="loopStatus">     
  <c:if test="${loopStatus.index < 2}">
    <td><div align = "center">${item}</div><td>
  </c:if>    
 </c:forEach>
</tr>
```

The `loopStatus` variable here can give you the 'index' of the current iteration.